# How can DiffUtil know about list changes when only the companion object has changed?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, android-diffutils

[image]

As shown in the image, I would like the unit of the `Detail item` to be changed at once according to the `toggle button`.

`Detail list items` were set as `companion objects` because it was determined that it was not necessary to have a `unit` property individually.

However, it seems that `DiffUtil` determines that there is no change between the `new list` and the `old list`, perhaps because the `unit` property is set as a `companion object`.

So there is no update of the view either.

How can I make DiffUtil responsive while changing the companion object?

---

**Detail**

```
@Entity
data class Detail(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int,
    val set: Int,
    var weight: String = "",
    var reps: String = "") {

    companion object {
        var title: String = ""
        var unit: String = "kg"
        val memo = ""
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
class DetailViewModel(application: Application) : ViewModel() {
    private val repository: DetailRepository
    private val _items: MutableLiveData<List<Detail>> = MutableLiveData()
    val items = _items
    private val list: List<Detail>
        get() = _items.value ?: emptyList()

    init {
        val detailDao = DetailDatabase.getDatabase(application)!!.detailDao()
        repository = DetailRepository(detailDao)
    }

    fun changeUnit(unit: String) {
        Detail.unit = unit
        if(list == null)
            return

        _items.postValue(list) // To notify the observer.
    }

    fun addDetail() {

        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
            val item = Detail(0, set = list.size+1)
            repository.add(item)

            // If use plus(), a new List is returned.
            // Therefore, the change is notified to the Observer by postValue of the new list added.
            _items.postValue(list.plus(item))

        }
    }
    fun deleteDetail() {
        // Delete the last set and return a new list to postValue to notify the Observer of the change.
        _items.postValue(list.dropLast(1))
    }
}
```

**DiffUtil**

```
class DetailDiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Detail>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(
        oldItem: Detail,
        newItem: Detail
    ): Boolean  {
       return (oldItem.id == newItem.id)
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(
        oldItem: Detail,
        newItem: Detail
    ): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
    }
}
```

**Fragment**

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    vm.items.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { newList ->
        adapter.submitList(newList)
    }
}
```

Comment: see [this](https://github.com/sarafanshul/Zoro/issues/2), it addresses the same issue and how to solve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Detail list items were set as companion objects because it was determined that it was not necessary to have a unit property individually.

This is the root of the problem. If you want `DiffUtil` to be able to "see" these changes, you will have to move this information out of the companion object.

`DiffUtil` works by taking in two instances of your class and doing work (the `areItemsTheSame()` and `areContentsTheSame()` methods) to see if anything has changed. Since this information is part of the companion object, it will always be identical for all instances, which means there's no way for `DiffUtil` to detect a change, even if one has happened.

Answer (score 1):

Like Ben P says, when you change the value in the companion object, that affects the entire class (since they all share that object). It's not included in the generated `equals()` code for the data class - because why would it need to be? Every instance shares the same value, it's not part of the state!

Even if it were, when you compare `oldList` and `newList`, `oldList` has still been "updated" with the new `unit` value, because it's in that shared companion object. If you want `oldList` and `newList` to be able to have different values for `unit`, they need to be per-instance properties.

---

But the way you're doing things here, the `unit` doesn't even seem to be part of the data, right? It's not like you're storing a value and a unit of measure, and doing conversions when the displayed unit type changes. It *looks like* this is just a general display option, that just applies to how the data is displayed.

So in that case, why not just call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter, or something similar? Force a redraw, let it show the new unit type, that's it. I'm not sure if you need to do anything special if you're using `DiffUtil`, but that's what I'd look into.

(I feel like storing the unit type in the data would be a way better approach, seems important to what the stored number actually *means*, but for what you're doing right now, a display refresh should be enough)